# Scala: Java to Scala, how to eliminate setters and getters and reduce code size

Tags: java, scala

Update: After suggestion from one of the experts here, I have cleaned up the following Java code:
There is a class called MyRespModifier and it holds two **inner static classes** called **ResponseMail** and **Response**
I have rewritten this code Scala as an exercise. Scala version: 2.11.2.          I am not happy with the results. It resembles Java, and looks like it could do with a large dose of  idiomatic Scala from the ground up. I would like to accomplish a reduction in the no of lines and also on inspection of the code it should stand out as elegant Scala code.At least my goal is to understand how some Java constructs can be rewritten in idiomatic Scala.

The Scala equivalent is posted after the Java code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;

public class MyRespModifier {

private static final String VERSION           = "1.0.0";
private static final String USER_AGENT  = "myuseragent/"+ VERSION + "java";
private static final String ARG_TO          = "to[%d]";
private static final String ARG_TONAME      = "toname[%d]";
private static final String ARG_CC          = "cc[%d]";
private static final String ARG_FROM        = "from";
private static final String ARG_FROMNAME    = "fromname";
private static final String ARG_REPLYTO     = "replyto";
private static final String ARG_SUBJECT     = "subject";
private static final String ARG_CONTENTS    = "content[%s]";
private static final String ARG_MYSMTPAPI    = "x-respModifierSmtpApi";

private String apikey;
private String apivalue;
private String apiUrlBasePath;
private String port;
private String endpoint;
private CloseableHttpClient client;

  public MyRespModifier() {
      this.apiUrlBasePath = "api/responseshaper/response";
      this.endpoint = "/myapi/mymail.dispatch.json";
      this.client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setUserAgent(USER_AGENT).build();
  }

  public MyRespModifier setUrl(String url) {
    this.apiUrlBasePath = apiUrlBasePath;
    return this;
  }

  public MyRespModifier setEndpoint(String endpoint) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
    return this;
  }


  public MyRespModifier setClient(CloseableHttpClient client) {
    this.client = client;
    return this;
  }



public HttpEntity constructRespBody(ResponseEmail respEmail) {
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

        builder.addTextBody("api_user", this.apikey);
        builder.addTextBody("api_key", this.apivalue);

        String[] tos = respEmail.getTos();
        String[] tonames = respEmail.getToNames();
        String[] ccs = respEmail.getCcs();

        if (tos.length == 0) {
          builder.addTextBody(String.format(ARG_TO, 0), respEmail.getFrom(), ContentType.create("text/plain", "UTF-8"));
        }
        for (int i = 0, len = tos.length; i < len; i++)
          builder.addTextBody(String.format(ARG_TO, i), tos[i], ContentType.create("text/plain", "UTF-8"));

        for (int i = 0, len = tonames.length; i < len; i++)
          builder.addTextBody(String.format(ARG_TONAME, i), tonames[i], ContentType.create("text/plain", "UTF-8"));

        for (int i = 0, len = ccs.length; i < len; i++)
          builder.addTextBody(String.format(ARG_CC, i), ccs[i], ContentType.create("text/plain", "UTF-8"));

        if (respEmail.getContentIds().size() > 0) {
          Iterator it = respEmail.getContentIds().entrySet().iterator();
          while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                builder.addTextBody(String.format(ARG_CONTENTS, entry.getKey()), (String) entry.getValue());
            }
        }

            if (respEmail.getFrom() != null && !respEmail.getFrom().isEmpty())
              builder.addTextBody(ARG_FROM, respEmail.getFrom(), ContentType.create("text/plain", "UTF-8"));

            if (respEmail.getFromName() != null && !respEmail.getFromName().isEmpty())
              builder.addTextBody(ARG_FROMNAME, respEmail.getFromName(), ContentType.create("text/plain", "UTF-8"));

            if (respEmail.getReplyTo() != null && !respEmail.getReplyTo().isEmpty())
              builder.addTextBody(ARG_REPLYTO, respEmail.getReplyTo(), ContentType.create("text/plain", "UTF-8"));

            if (respEmail.getSubject() != null && !respEmail.getSubject().isEmpty())
              builder.addTextBody(ARG_SUBJECT, respEmail.getSubject(), ContentType.create("text/plain", "UTF-8"));

            String tmpString = respEmail.respModifierSmtpApi.jsonString();
            if (!tmpString.equals("{}"))
              builder.addTextBody(ARG_MYSMTPAPI, tmpString, ContentType.create("text/plain", "UTF-8"));

            return builder.build();
  } //end of method constructRespBody

  public MyRespModifier.Response send(ResponseEmail respMail) throws RespModifierException {
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(this.apiUrlBasePath + this.endpoint);
    httppost.setEntity(this.constructRespBody(respMail));
    try {
      HttpResponse res = this.client.execute(httppost);
      return new MyRespModifier.Response(res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), EntityUtils.toString(res.getEntity()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RespModifierException(e);
    }

  }

  //*********************************************************************

  public static class ResponseEmail {
    private MyExperimentalApi respModifierSmtpApi;
    private ArrayList<String> to;
    private ArrayList<String> toname;
    private ArrayList<String> cc;
    private String from;
    private String fromname;
    private String replyto;
    private String subject;
    private String text;
    private Map<String, String> contents;
    private Map<String, String> headers;

    public ResponseEmail () {
      this.respModifierSmtpApi = new MyExperimentalApi();
      this.to = new ArrayList<String>();
      this.toname = new ArrayList<String>();
      this.cc = new ArrayList<String>();
      this.contents = new HashMap<String, String>();
      this.headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
public ResponseEmail addTo(String to) {
  this.to.add(to);
  return this;
}

public ResponseEmail addTo(String[] tos) {
  this.to.addAll(Arrays.asList(tos));
  return this;
}

public ResponseEmail addTo(String to, String name) {
  this.addTo(to);
  return this.addToName(name);
}

public ResponseEmail setTo(String[] tos) {
  this.to = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tos));
  return this;
}

public String[] getTos() {
  return this.to.toArray(new String[this.to.size()]);
}

public ResponseEmail addSmtpApiTo(String to) {
  this.respModifierSmtpApi.addTo(to);
  return this;
}

public ResponseEmail addSmtpApiTo(String[] to) {
  this.respModifierSmtpApi.addTos(to);
  return this;
}



public ResponseEmail addToName(String toname) {
      this.toname.add(toname);
      return this;
    }

public ResponseEmail addToName(String[] tonames) {
  this.toname.addAll(Arrays.asList(tonames));
  return this;
}

public ResponseEmail setToName(String[] tonames) {
  this.toname = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tonames));
  return this;
}

public String[] getToNames() {
  return this.toname.toArray(new String[this.toname.size()]);
}

public ResponseEmail addCc(String cc) {
  this.cc.add(cc);
  return this;
}

public ResponseEmail addCc(String[] ccs) {
  this.cc.addAll(Arrays.asList(ccs));
  return this;
}

public ResponseEmail setCc(String[] ccs) {
  this.cc = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(ccs));
  return this;
}

public String[] getCcs() {
  return this.cc.toArray(new String[this.cc.size()]);
}

public ResponseEmail setFrom(String from) {
  this.from = from;
  return this;
}

public String getFrom() {
  return this.from;
}

public ResponseEmail setFromName(String fromname) {
  this.fromname = fromname;
  return this;
}

public String getFromName() {
  return this.fromname;
}

public ResponseEmail setReplyTo(String replyto) {
  this.replyto = replyto;
  return this;
}

public String getReplyTo() {
  return this.replyto;
}


public ResponseEmail setSubject(String subject) {
  this.subject = subject;
  return this;
}

public String getSubject() {
  return this.subject;
}

public ResponseEmail setText(String text) {
  this.text = text;
  return this;
}

public String getText() {
  return this.text;
}


public JSONObject getFilters() {
  return this.respModifierSmtpApi.getFilters();
}


public ResponseEmail addContentId(String attachmentName, String cid) {
      this.contents.put(attachmentName, cid);
      return this;
}

public Map getContentIds() {
      return this.contents;
}

public ResponseEmail addHeader(String key, String val) {
  this.headers.put(key, val);
  return this;
}

public Map getHeaders() {
  return this.headers;
}

public MyExperimentalApi getSMTPAPI() {
  return this.respModifierSmtpApi;
}
```

}

```
public static class Response {
    private int code;
    private boolean success;
    private String message;

    public Response(int code, String msg) {
      this.code = code;
      this.success = code == 200;
      this.message = msg;
    }

    public int getCode() {
      return this.code;
    }

    public boolean getStatus() {
      return this.success;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
      return this.message;
    }
```

}//end of class Response

Comment: There's an extra " at the end of line 28. Your Java class doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will make the correction

Comment: Could you list some specific things that you would like to get improved? I guess you want things such as implicit typing and better importing. Also simple methods can be written as one-liners in Scala. No need for braces.

Comment: Seems like a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bubletan, some specific things in the Scala class I would like improved are: 1) I would like to have a "class MyRespModifier" instead of it being an object.                                                                               2) I would like 'class ResponseEmail" in a separate class or object. (Do you think having it as a trait would be better)                                                                                                       3) class MyRespModifier is currently inside the outer object MyRespModifer - it looks very confusing to me. How do I refactor that?

Comment: @Bubletan, yes..implicit typing and better importing.

Comment: @user3825558 In Scala you place static fields and methods in `object`, but you can have a `class` with the same name.

Comment: @Bubletan, "you can have a class with the same name". Could you be more specific about that? Thanks

Comment: Basically, you have both `object MyRespModifier` and `class MyRespModifier`, where the `object` represents the static part of the class and the `class` an instance.

Comment: Got you. So what you saying is: object MyRespModifier and class MyRespModifier can be separate bodies of code residing in the same file. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, when you access it statically, e.g. `MyRespModifier.method()`, it uses the `object` and when you access it from an instance, it uses the `class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the imports to save some lines

```
import java.util.Arrays
import java.util.HashMap
import java.util.Iterator
```

becomes

```
import java.util.{Arrays, HashMap, Iterator}
```

The getters and setters can be generated for you. This is a feature of a Scala class if you declare the constructor parameter with `val` or `var`.

A simplified version of your class becomes:

```
class ResponseEmail(var to: ArrayList[String], var cc: ArrayList[String])
```

This getters are `cc` and `to` and the setters are `cc_=` and `to_=`

```
scala> res6.
asInstanceOf   cc   cc_=   isInstanceOf   to   toString   to_=
```

Comment: I am adding in the changes you suggested. Thanks

Comment: "The getters and setters can be generated for you" - So I can get rid of the setters and getters then?

Comment: Okay, I got it. I just declare the class the way you suggested. Thanks

Comment: @user3825558 yes. You can copy and paste that class in the REPL/worksheet and try it out.

Comment: Okay, I verified this in the REPL:                                                            scala> class ResponseEmail(var to: ArrayList[String], var cc: ArrayList[String])
defined class ResponseEmail

Comment: Now my question is: the two vars, to and cc, have they also been instantiated as: cc = new ArrayList[Sting]() and likewise for cc   ?

Comment: @user3825558 yes, they are initially empty an `ArrayList`. From the REPL `scala> res6.cc
res8: java.util.ArrayList[String] = []`